# Recurrence without intuitive leaps

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations

I've just picked up 'Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science' and I'm already intimidated by the first problem.
The problem involves the classic Tower of Hanoi. That is, there are three polls or "pegs" and eight disks of decreasing sizes with holes stacked one on top of the other so that the disks are all on one of the polls. 
"The objective is to transfer the entire tower to one of the other pegs, moving only one disk at a time and never moving a larger one onto a smaller." 
The mathematical problem is this: "How many moves are necessary and sufficient to perform the task?"
The text walks us through starting small thinking through the cases if there was only 1 disk, or 2 disks, and so on. 
Let us say that `Hanoi[n] =` *the minimum number of moves that will transfer n disks from one peg to another*. 
Just by playing with this puzzle we know that if there is one disk, it only takes one move, and if there are two disks one moves the first disk to another peg, the second to the remaining peg, and the first disk one onto the second disk. That is three moves. Thus:

```
Hanoi[1] == 1
Hanoi[2] == 3
```

We also know that if there are no disks there will be no moves.

```
Hanoi[0] == 0
```

To generalize this we think through adding another disk, if we could previously transfer *n-1* disks in *Hanoi[n-1]* moves then we transfer *n-1* disks to another peg, transfer the remaining larger disk to the remaining peg, and transfer those same *n-1* disks onto the remaining disk. That is:

```
Hanoi[n-1] + 1 + Hanoi[n-1]
```

or

```
Hanoi[n] == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+1
```

I'm starting to understand that this incremental strategy is the essence of recurrence, I think. 
So we now have a set of equalities that we are told is called a recurrence:

```
Hanoi[0] == 0
Hanoi[n] == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+1
```

To solve this recurrence we are guided to initially guess the solution by solving for more values:

```
Hanoi == { 0, 2*Hanoi[1-1]+1, 2*Hanoi[2-1]+1, 2*Hanoi[3-1]+1, 2*Hanoi[4-1]+1, 2*Hanoi[5-1]+1, ... }
Hanoi == { 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, ... }
```

With this series of numbers our intuition tells us it is exponential, and we can guess:

```
Hanoi[n] == 2^n-1
```

It is then explained to us how to solve recurrences without relying on intuition.
First we're told to add one to the both sides of the equality:

```
Hanoi[0]+1 == 0+1
Hanoi[n]+1 == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+1+1
```

or

```
Hanoi[0]+1 == 1
Hanoi[n]+1 == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+2
```

We are then told to let *`TowerOf[n] = Hanoi[n]+1`* showing that:

```
TowerOf[0] == Hanoi[0]+1 == 1
TowerOf[n] == 2*TowerOf[n-1]
```

This is where I no longer follow. I don't understand the substitution in the second equation. My question is this: How did we lose the +2 in this substitution? I successively compute the TowerOf series as follows:

```
TowerOf == { 1, 2*TowerOf[1-1], 2*TowerOf[2-1], 2*Towerof[3-1], ... }
TowerOf == { 1, 2, 4, 8, ... }
```

The text goes on to say that this is transparently `TowerOf[n] == 2^n` and therefore `Hanoi[n] == 2^n-1` but I'm stuck, I don't understand the substitution itself. How does it follow that `TowerOf[n] == 2*TowerOf[n-1]` and how do I derive `2*TowerOf[n-1]` from `2*Hanoi[n-1]+2`? 
Is this not also just an intuitive leap? or am I missing an obvious but not illustrated derivation?

Answer (score 5):

If you understand this one:

`Hanoi[n]+1 == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+1+1`

then you can simply rewrite it as:

`Hanoi[n]+1 == 2*(Hanoi[n-1]+1)`

which is equivalent to:

`TowerOf[n] == 2*(TowerOf[n-1])`

Answer (score 2):

Since multiplication distributes over addition, `2*Hanoi[n-1]+2 = 2*(Hanoi[n-1]+1)`.

(And `Hanoi[n-1]+1=TowerOf[n-1]` by definition.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Hanoi[n]+1 == 2*Hanoi[n-1]+2
```

So

```
Hanoi[n]+1 == 2 * (Hanoi[n-1] + 1).
```

Then

```
TowerOf[n] = Hanoi[n]+1
```

has the two specializations

```
TowerOf[n] = Hanoi[n]+1 
TowerOf[n-1] = Hanoi[n-1]+1.
```

Using those in the above,

```
TowerOf[n] == 2 * (Hanoi[n-1] + 1)
    == 2 * TowerOf[n-1].
```

Now, what is

```
TowerOf[n] == 2 * TowerOf[n-1]
TowerOf[n-1] == 2 * TowerOf[n-2]
TowerOf[n-2] == 2 * TowerOf[n-3]
    ...
TowerOf[1] == 2 * TowerOf[0]
TowerOf[0] == 1
```

Notice that we accumulate $n$ copies of $2$, as we use this sequence of expansions, multiplied by a final $1$.  So this is $2^n$.